# Meaning of the "greater than" operator when using sets

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation, set-partition

Consider the following construction,

$$\sum_{\rho'\in\mathcal{P}(n), \rho'>\rho} f(\rho)$$

where $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are partitions of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is the set of all possible partitions.

Here, I would like to know the meaning of $\rho' > \rho$. Can anyone give me a hint? I interpret:

> $\rho'$ in the set $\mathcal{P}(n)$ such that $\rho'$ is greater than $\rho$.

Does it mean I should choose $\rho'$ that has more elements than $\rho$?

Answer (score 2):

It means $\rho'$ is finer than $\rho$ in the sense that every set in $\rho$ is a union of some sets from $\rho'$.

For example $\{1,\{2,3,..,n\}\}$ and $\{1, \{2\}, \{3,4,..,n\}\}$ are two partitions of $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ and the second one is finer than the first.

Comment: Thanks!! This is amazing!